# How to disable/hide excel rows using Apache POI + Java

Tags: java, excel, apache, apache-poi

I am creating an excel file using apache poi. Here is my code snippet:

```
Workbook workbook = new Workbook();
XSSFSheet sheet = (XSSFSheet) workbook.createSheet(); 
for (Payment payment : paymentList) {    
             XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(rowCount++);
             row.createCell(0).setCellValue(i);
             row.createCell(1).setCellValue(payment.getBenificiaryName());
             row.createCell(2).setCellValue(payment.getMobileNo());
             row.createCell(3).setCellValue(payment.getCompanyName());
             row.createCell(4).setCellValue(payment.getAddress());      
        }
```

I want to disable all the rest of the cells, columns, rows except my created cells just like the attached picture. How can I do this using Apache POI. Any help, suggestion is highly appreciated. Thanks

[image]

Comment: what do you mean u want to hide them? just don't add them to the excel 0-0

Comment: There is nothing hidden or disabled in your attached picture. This is simply the View "Page Break Preview" and a Print Area B1:I??? is defined.

Comment: @nafas, I've attached an image with my post. I want to create my excel file just like that. Hide or disable or change color of unused cells to gray, what ever you wish to call it. :)

Comment: @SaquibulIslamWaheed well the attached image is not an excel file to begin with. beside I still not sure what you mean the unused cells

Answer (score 0):

In case this helps someone, you can set `row.setZeroHeight(true)` to hide a row. So if you loop through all the rows you want to hide using their indices and set their heights to zero, you'll be able to hide all of them